# PostgreSQL - how build a where clause from nested array

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a query:

```sql
SELECT …
FROM …
WHERE project = 123
AND (
    file = file1 and fieldidx = idx1
OR  file = file2 and fieldidx = idx2
OR  …)
```

… I want to create the where clause in a function that has the required array of tuples, where the tuple is a user type (file text, idx smallint).

I don’t know how (I’m trying to avoid using a union).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function to do that. Just check whether the tuple is in the provided array:

```
SELECT …
FROM …
WHERE project = 123
AND (file, fieldidx) IN ((file1, idx1), (file2, idx2), …);
```

or

```
SELECT …
FROM …
WHERE project = 123
AND (file, fieldidx) = ANY( ARRAY[(file1, idx1), (file2, idx2), …] );
```

Comment: This looks great. To clarify my intended use of a function: it’s a stored procedure for client requests. What you provided will generate the sql statement as I intended.

Comment: You should not generate SQL statements as text. You should just execute them, with the array value as a parameter (`… AND (file, fieldids) = ANY ($1)`).